# Convert SQLite to JSON

Tags: android, json

when i add data using  SQLite is it possible to convert the data to JSON so that when I retrieve data it should be parsed and fetch data.If possible explain with example.

Comment: Do you mean you are adding data to your database not in `JSON` but you want it in `JSON` format when you fetch it back?

Comment: Doesn't my answer help?

Comment: @PoojaNM, store JSON in form of string like: your_json.toString() and while retreive get String from database and then convert into JSON Object like: JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(your_string_from_databse);

Comment: You may accept an answer or post your own answer that resolved your query.

(That tick button besides the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch data from your `SQLiteDatabase`, it is returned in a `Cursor`. Unfortunately there's no such direct format to convert data from a cursor to JSON, but you can do it with some code like:

```
private JSONArray convertCursorToJSON(Cursor cursor) {
  JSONArray result = new JSONArray();

  int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
    for (int index = 0; index < columnCount; index++) {
      row.put(cursor.getColumnName(index), cursor.getString(index));
    }
    result.put(row);
  }
  cursor.close();

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can modify and use the following according to your need.

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    //wordList should be your arraylistdata or values etc which you want to insert 
    //Use GSON to serialize Array List to JSON
   gson.toJson(wordList);
```

use this while storing your data

Answer (score 1):

Convert the data to String when you are storing

```
jsonObject.toString();
```

On retrieve you can get the json by converting the String.

```
JSONObject asdf = new JSONObject(<retrieved data>);
```